# CSVWriter don't allow to write to file

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner, filewriter, csv-write-stream

I want to save my data into CSV file. I'm using Scanner to read -> CSVWriter to save.

I got error: incompatibile types: List[String] can't be converted to String[].

method:

```
private static void insertToFile(String source, String target)
{   
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(source));

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        data.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
    sc.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

       File resfile = new File(target);      

        try{
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(resfile, true));

             //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

            for (String j : data) {
              //writer.writeAll(data);//error here
            }

               writer.close();
            }
        catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, if `writeAll()` requires an array to be passed you can't directly pass a list. Try converting it first, e.g. `writer.writeAll(data.toArray( new String[] )`.

Comment: You dont need a for loop inthat case just write `writer.writeAll(data.toArray(new String[]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

`writer.writeAll` accept a `String[]` as input, you are passing a `List<String>`

changing

```
for (String j : data) {
   //writer.writeAll(data);//error here
}
```

to

`writer.writeAll(data.toArray(new String[data.size()]));` will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way of doing it,you can use the below mentioned code.
Import these dependencies in your code(import java.io.File,import java.io.FileWriter).

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(File_path));
writer.write(data);
writer.close();
```

Comment: I removed all starting from File resfile = new File(target).....and put your code. Now I got error: no suitable method found fro write(List[String])

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
private static void insertToFile(String source, String target)
{
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    // utilize Scanner implementing AutoCloseable and try-with-resource construct 
    // see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html )
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(source))) {
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            data.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File resfile = new File(target);

    try {
        // depending on the CSVWriter implementation consider using try-with-resource as above
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(resfile, true));

        writer.writeAll(data.toArray(new String[data.size()]));

        writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It converts the list into an array initialized to the length of your list. Also you probably don't want to call `writeAll` on your entire list for each element in your list, which prints your list into your files multiple times.